# problem in exporting pdf of heatmap from R

Tags: r

I am trying to export the heatmap using:

```
pdf("y2.pdf", width = 7, height = 20);
textMatrix = paste(signif(moduleTraitCor, 2), "\n(",
                   signif(moduleTraitPvalue, 1), ")", sep = "");
dim(textMatrix) = dim(moduleTraitCor)
sizeGrWindow(9,7)
par(mar = c(8, 10, 3, 3));

labeledHeatmap(Matrix = moduleTraitCor,
               xLabels = colnames(datTraits),
               yLabels = names(MEs),
               ySymbols = names(MEs),
               colorLabels = FALSE,
               cex.lab = NULL, 
               cex.lab.x = 0.6,
               cex.lab.y = 0.3,
               xColorWidth = 0.01,
               yColorWidth = 0.1,
               colors = greenWhiteRed(83),
               textMatrix = textMatrix,
               setStdMargins = FALSE,
               cex.text = 0.2,
               zlim = c(-1,1),
               margins =c(12,9),  
               main = paste("Module-trait_relationships"))
dev.off()
```

However, the exported `y2.pdf` file does not open. Can anyone help me finding what is going wrong. Thank you!

Comment: Can you specify the the output after you run the command? You not need `;` for non one-line input  in general in `R`. An  easy to test where the problem is might be; `pdf("y2.pdf") ;plot(1) ; dev.off()`

Comment: Thank you! I get the output plot and there is no error. But the plot is not exported.

Comment: Try this code https://pastebin.com/1ufyZrTR  Can you open the `y2.pdf` file ?